# How to obtain the report data from BO with the use of RESTful Web Services?

Tags: business-objects-sdk

I would appreciate the sample code (URL String) that returns the data.
So far I am able to get the information about the report but I am not able to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://help.sap.com/saphelpiis_sbo41sp4wi-sdk/frameset.htm?45f89e086e041014910aba7db0e91070.html

Get the list of data providers:

```
GET <webiURL>/documents/{documentId}/dataproviders
```

Within the result you'll get the DP IDs that look like:

```
<id>DP0</id>
```

Then get the number of "flows" in the DP:

```
GET <webiURL>/documents/{documentId}/dataproviders/DP/flows/count
```

Then get the flow data:

```
GET <webiURL>/documents/{documentId}/dataproviders/DP0/flows/0
```

Comment: Hey Joe!!! I tried this and when executed first line of your code I got an error. {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 08:57:07 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 60
  Content-Type: application/json
}}

Comment: @Jacek: Run the query in Fiddler (making sure to include the login-token in the headers) and see if the URL returned any extra error message information.