# How to get the raw data from particular document's schedule instance?

Tags: business-objects-sdk

I am now able to get the data from a document usign RESTful Web Services SDK

as per

[How to obtain the report data from BO with the use of RESTful Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733500/how-to-obtain-the-report-data-from-bo-with-the-use-of-restful-web-services)

and what I need is to
get the data not from the current version of the document but from the schedule that were executed some time ago
with the older data than the current data.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt that it is possible to get the IDs of schedules for a particular document.

Then it is possible to get an export of the schedule's content by requesting the export but instaed of providing documents ID, it is necessary to provide schedule ID.

This way I obtained the schedule/instance export.

I also have noticed the limitation that the pagind does NOT seem to work when the export is requested from schedule's ID instead of document's ID.